# When is start method invoked by ExecutorService in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, executorservice, callable

I'm learning about `ExecutorService` in a simple Spring Boot project. And I know that `ExecutorService` uses `submit` method to submit tasks and it will uses different threads for every task. And I don't understand where exactly are the new threads started. I know that a thread is started using method `start`. Can somebody explain me where is invoked the `start` method?

For example, this is my code:

```
try {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    Future<Accounts> accountFuture =
            executorService.submit(
                    () -> accountsRepository.findByCustomerId(customer.getCustomerId()));

    Future<List<Loans>> loansFuture =
            executorService.submit(
                    () -> loansFeignClient.getLoansDetails(correlationId, customer));

    Future<List<Cards>> cardsFuture =
            executorService.submit(
                    () -> cardsFeignClient.getCardDetails(correlationId, customer));

    executorService.shutdown();
    Accounts account;

    try {
        executorService.awaitTermination(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        account = accountFuture.get();
    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException ex) {
        logger.warn("Exception for accountFuture.get() = {}", ex);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
    }

    List<Loans> loansList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Cards> cardsList = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        loansList.addAll(loansFuture.get());
    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException ex) {
        logger.warn(ex.toString());
        logger.warn("The call to GET loans details failed! Returning empty contactDetails body!");
    }

    try {
        cardsList.addAll(cardsFuture.get());
    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException ex) {
        logger.warn(ex.toString());
        logger.warn("The call to GET cards details failed! Returning empty contactDetails body!");
    }

    ...
```

Is the new thread started when the `submit` method is invoked or when the `get` method is invoked? And when is invoked the `start` method?
Thank you! Any feedback will be appreciated!

Comment: when a new Thread is needed. The Executor will maintain a pool (collection) of threads to run the tasks. These Threads are re-used for new tasks, that is, they do not need to be started for every task¹. If the pool has no available Thread and its capacity is not yet fully used, a new Thread will (may be) created and started when `submit` is called. Also consult the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)) of `newFixedThreadPool`, and of related classes. || **¹** A Thread can only be started once

Comment: I think you're confusing (or conflating) the method `run` of `Runnable` for the method `start` of `Thread`.

Answer (score 0):

ExecutorService is another layer on top of Threads.

You dont have to manage the threads yourself, the ExecutorService is doing this for you.

```
Future<Accounts> accountFuture = executorService.submit(() -> accountsRepository.findByCustomerId(customer.getCustomerId()));
```

this is already starting a new thread. You get a future returned to tell you the state of the computation (if its finished, the result etc).

Under the hood the ExecutorService is doing the new Thread().start() things automatically.

Comment: Generally, executor services do not start a thread when you submit a job, they - usually - already have a pool of threads to run submitted jobs (using a queue for the jobs).